# Want to extract values which is in a webpage as dictionary format using python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, web-scraping, data-science

I want to scrap Name, Phone Number and email from the webpage but it seems like the entire detail is in dictionary which is inside a dictionary someone please correct me I am confused how I am going to extract these values in there particular column. Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

url ='https://mainapi.dadeschools.net/api/v1/employees?limit=10&skip=0&sortDesc=false'
R = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
with open('school.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8', newline ='') as f:
thewriter = writer(f)
header = ['Name', 'Location', 'Phone Number', 'Email' ]
thewriter.writerow(header)
thewriter.writerow(soup)
```

Comment: Try reproducing your response as a dictionary in an interactive mode (in python terminal): `R = requests.get(url)` and then `response = R.json()`. Now, that you have this nested dictionary saved in `response` variable, you can play with indexing to see how to get the desired values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It do not need `BeautifulSoup` as mentioned simply requets the api and transform JSON via [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to CSV.

##### Example

```
import requests, csv

url ='https://mainapi.dadeschools.net/api/v1/employees?limit=10&skip=0&sortDesc=false'
data = requests.get(url).json()['items']
data
with open('my.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, data[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

##### EDIT

As mentioned by ***Barry the Platipus*** there is also one and more methods to go with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.json_normalize(
    pd.read_json('https://mainapi.dadeschools.net/api/v1/employees?limit=10&skip=0&sortDesc=false')['items']
).to_csv('my.csv', index=False)
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.read_json('https://mainapi.dadeschools.net/api/v1/employees?limit=10&skip=0&sortDesc=false')['items']\
    .values.tolist()
).to_csv('my.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Was just writing a response based on pandas json_normalize() - although read_json would also work here, then noticed yours. Maybe update yours, give him a pandas solution as well.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Added your mentioned alternatives based on `pandas` hope this will meets your approaches.